# Example to use scale_factor and add_offset in netCDF4 with Python?

Tags: python, compression, netcdf4

From the documentation of netCDF4 here :
http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Variable

Who could give me a simple example of writing data using scale_factor and add_offset parameters in Python ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know how to use `add_offset` and `scale_factor` parameters to pack or unpack data in `.nc` file, you can read [here](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2010/bestpractices/Packing.html).
When you read netCDF4 file with python ([download NCEP reanalysis I data for example](ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.derived/surface/air.mon.mean.nc)), you can reference following code:

```py
>>> import netCDF4 as nc

>>> file_obj = nc.Dataset('./air.mon.mean.nc')

>>> file_obj.variables.keys()
odict_keys(['lat', 'lon', 'time', 'air'])
```

we want to read the `air` variable and check it by

```py
file_obj.variables['air']
```

it will show that:

```
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 air(time, lat, lon)
    long_name: Monthly Mean Air Temperature at sigma level 0.995
    valid_range: [-2000.  2000.]
    units: degC
    add_offset: 0.0
    scale_factor: 1.0
    missing_value: -9.96921e+36
    precision: 1
    least_significant_digit: 0
    var_desc: Air Temperature
    level_desc: Surface
    statistic: Mean
    parent_stat: Individual Obs
    dataset: NCEP Reanalysis Derived Products
    actual_range: [-73.78001  42.14595]
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (848, 73, 144)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
```

we can read `add_offset` and `scale_factor` by

```py
>>> add_offset = file_obj.variables['air'].add_offset
>>> scale_factor = file_obj.variables['air'].scale_factor
```

then read packed_value by

```py
>>> packed_value = file_obj.variables['air'][:]
```

finally, we can calculate upacked_value(real value) with pack expression by

```py
>>> unpacked_value = packed_value * scale_factor + add_offset
```

the result:

```
>>> unpacked_value
array([[[-34.926773  , -34.926773  , -34.926773  , ..., -34.926773  ,
         -34.926773  , -34.926773  ],
        [-35.13935   , -35.129673  , -35.12742   , ..., -35.188705  ,
         -35.170002  , -35.14935   ],
        [-34.352573  , -34.04226   , -33.768707  , ..., -35.333866  ,
         -35.002903  , -34.671288  ],
        ...,
        [-16.525156  , -16.404509  , -16.284832  , ..., -16.795155  ,
         -16.737736  , -16.643543  ],
        [-16.190313  , -16.202248  , -16.21677   , ..., -16.132574  ,
         -16.161928  , -16.178377  ],
        [-17.697733  , -17.697733  , -17.697733  , ..., -17.697733  ,
         -17.697733  , -17.697733  ]],

       [[-33.311375  , -33.311375  , -33.311375  , ..., -33.311375  ,
         -33.311375  , -33.311375  ],
        [-34.65034   , -34.476204  , -34.29689   , ..., -35.18448   ,
         -35.009308  , -34.835514  ],
        [-34.1031    , -33.619995  , -33.161373  , ..., -35.606552  ,
         -35.103443  , -34.602757  ],
        ...,
        [-34.338963  , -34.21862   , -34.08241   , ..., -34.359997  ,
         -34.42724   , -34.418617  ],
        [-33.795513  , -33.896553  , -33.977238  , ..., -33.41517   ,
         -33.56758   , -33.690342  ],
        [-32.942413  , -32.942413  , -32.942413  , ..., -32.942413  ,
         -32.942413  , -32.942413  ]],

       [[-29.716127  , -29.716127  , -29.716127  , ..., -29.716127  ,
         -29.716127  , -29.716127  ],
        [-29.4471    , -29.499353  , -29.551613  , ..., -29.365162  ,
         -29.385166  , -29.41258   ],
        [-28.544516  , -28.366776  , -28.227749  , ..., -29.282906  ,
         -29.01323   , -28.763546  ],
        ...,
        [-51.964516  , -52.206455  , -52.362263  , ..., -50.628704  ,
         -51.18032   , -51.631298  ],
        [-52.846123  , -53.07613   , -53.290974  , ..., -52.069355  ,
         -52.344517  , -52.60097   ],
        [-54.835476  , -54.835476  , -54.835476  , ..., -54.835476  ,
         -54.835476  , -54.835476  ]],

       ...,

       [[  0.7949912 ,   0.7949912 ,   0.7949912 , ...,   0.7949912 ,
           0.7949912 ,   0.7949912 ],
        [  0.4383262 ,   0.44082558,   0.44582742, ...,   0.44332498,
           0.44166178,   0.43915424],
        [  0.85249335,   0.9124919 ,   0.9749919 , ...,   0.6591595 ,
           0.7224956 ,   0.7849895 ],
        ...,
        [-47.735012  , -47.71085   , -47.643345  , ..., -47.286682  ,
         -47.53668   , -47.68001   ],
        [-48.136677  , -48.31417   , -48.46751   , ..., -47.466675  ,
         -47.71334   , -47.937504  ],
        [-49.84001   , -49.84001   , -49.84001   , ..., -49.84001   ,
         -49.84001   , -49.84001   ]],

       [[  2.017739  ,   2.017739  ,   2.017739  , ...,   2.017739  ,
           2.017739  ,   2.017739  ],
        [  1.7024138 ,   1.6927387 ,   1.6862857 , ...,   1.7282208 ,
           1.719346  ,   1.7040253 ],
        [  2.255639  ,   2.275     ,   2.2983825 , ...,   2.1927364 ,
           2.2120905 ,   2.2282214 ],
        ...,
        [-55.12824   , -55.170174  , -55.13468   , ..., -54.45      ,
         -54.787907  , -55.01049   ],
        [-54.267754  , -54.429844  , -54.56291   , ..., -53.68952   ,
         -53.907265  , -54.09678   ],
        [-56.350006  , -56.350006  , -56.350006  , ..., -56.350006  ,
         -56.350006  , -56.350006  ]],

       [[  1.2532172 ,   1.2532172 ,   1.2532172 , ...,   1.2532172 ,
           1.2532172 ,   1.2532172 ],
        [  0.5870904 ,   0.59515494,   0.60886717, ...,   0.5814466 ,
           0.5798341 ,   0.5846687 ],
        [  0.99273497,   1.063704  ,   1.137088  , ...,   0.8080569 ,
           0.860479  ,   0.9241818 ],
        ...,
        [-52.7613    , -52.795174  , -52.786297  , ..., -52.214523  ,
         -52.4871    , -52.66856   ],
        [-52.11856   , -52.348392  , -52.553234  , ..., -51.348396  ,
         -51.628242  , -51.880657  ],
        [-53.070175  , -53.070175  , -53.070175  , ..., -53.070175  ,
         -53.070175  , -53.070175  ]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks, the first link shows example I was looking for, but I though a Python library already existed to manage this...